# Iniciar prueba automatizada selenium WebDriver Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, chromedriver

Estoy intentando iniciar una prueba en Chrome con Selenium WebDriver pero no avanza de `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

Estoy utilizando maven version de Chrome Driver Selenium:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.46.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Clase para la prueba

```
WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void prueba() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://google.com");
    System.out.println("CORRECTO 1");
}

@AfterClass
public void tear() {
    driver.close();
}
```

Comment: ¿No falta un `/` en tu ruta: `"C:Program Files ..."` debe ser `"C:/Program Files ..."`?

Comment: Gracias, voy a probarlo.

Answer (score 3):

Trata modificando la primera linea de tu método `prueba()` por:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Debe ser "`chromedriver.exe`" no "`chrome.exe`", verifica la ruta correcta del archivo.